# finding the standard deviation of each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.x

how could I modify this code:

```
def SD(numList):
    cntN=len(numList)
    sumN=0
    for i in numList:
        sumN+=i
    avgVal=float(sumN)/float(cntN)
    sumVar=0.0
    for i in range(cntN):
        sumVar+=float((numList[i]-avgVal)**2)
    return ((float(sumVar)/float((cntN-1)))**0.5)
```

so that it will work if numList is a list of lists and I want to find the standard deviation of each row?
any help is appreciated

Comment: This is exactly what list comprehensions and the `map` function are for: to apply some expression or some function (respectively) to each element in a sequence and put the results in a new list.

Comment: Also, you're not asking anything related to standard deviations; it's better to write a stripped-down example without any extraneous stuff (e.g., given a one-line function that just returns the length of a list, how do you change it to return the lengths of each list in a list of lists)? And definitely don't add tags for things that you aren't having problems with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def SD(numLists):
    def singleSD(numList):
      cntN=len(numList)
      sumN=0
      for i in numList:
          sumN+=i
      avgVal=float(sumN)/float(cntN)
      sumVar=0.0
      for i in range(cntN):
          sumVar+=float((numList[i]-avgVal)**2)
      return ((float(sumVar)/float((cntN-1)))**0.5)
    return [singleSD(l) for l in numLists]
```

Comment: I get a similar error (`sumVar += ((i - avgVal) for i in A)**2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'generator' and 'int'`) when I try it your way

Comment: It's because `((i - avgVal) for i in A)` is a generator expression in the statement you've written. Try `sumVar = sum((i - avgVal)**2 for i in A)`.

Comment: would there be an easy way to only use the positive numbers in the list?

Comment: `sumVar = sum((i - avgVal)**2 for i in A if i >= 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the modifying the code, it is easier to do a list comprehension:

```
[SD(nl) for nl in numLists]
```

Also, your `SD` function can be simplified using list comprehensions as:

```
def SD(numList):
    cntN = len(numList)
    avgVal = float(sum(numList))/cntN
    return (sum((i-avgVal)**2 for i in numList)/(cntN-1))**0.5
```

You also had a lot of redundant `Float`'s

Comment: I keep getting this error :`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'float'` any ideas as to how to fix that?

Comment: Fixed now. I was missing a paren in the return.